# Visual Studio 2019 x64 app using mongocxx driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, visual-studio-2019, mongo-cxx-driver, vcpkg

I'm trying to get a windows x64 C++ project working with the latest mongocxx driver using Visual Studio 2019. I installed the driver libraries using vcpkg:

vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver[boost]

In VS 2019 I created a new console app and inserted the example code from the mongo driver page into main(). I built the app and ran it; everything works great.  Then I noticed that it built as a win 32 app and switched it over to x64. Now the project won't build b/c it can't find the header files. Specifically (1rst error only...the others are similar)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'bsoncxx/json.hpp': No such file or directory

What do I need to do to make it work on the x64 platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, it was something I just didn't know to do. From Neumann-A on the vcpkg github site:

vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver[boost]:x64-windows

or

vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver[boost] --triplet x64-windows

or

set VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=x64-windows
vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver[boost]